SSRS Pivot is not summarizing
having this setup:

it hides and shows the group rows correctly, but does not hide and summarize the values accordingly:

what i am missing?
in the center one line with RE2400919 and a sum of 249.5 would be expected.
I started from scratch with this example and already have a working one but do not see the difference.
thanks in advance for any help
